# Column validation sharepoint list.Whats wrong with this formula

Tags: calculated-column-formula, validation-list-items, column-validation

H All,

I have a date i need to validate to make sure the user picks a date not less that todays date.
I typed in this formula below

```
="Review Date"<TODAY()
```

that works for the validation. but when i chose a date that is after todays date i can't submit the form
Any ideas

Comment: Try `=[Review Date]>TODAY()`

Answer (score 1):

Use **=[Review Date]>TODAY()** in column validation.
Tested for Date after Today's date. it is allowing to submit item.

[image]

Result:

[image]